# Apache POI: Retrieve highlighted text for comment

Tags: java, apache-poi, comments

I'm trying to retrieve all comments in a document using Apache POI along with the text that was selected for the comment. I can retrieve the text of the comments, but can't figure out how to determine the text that was highlighted/selected for the comment.

The code below will provide the comment text.

Any direction on how to retrieve the selected text?

```
String fileName = "test.docx";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
XWPFDocument xdoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
List<XWPFParagraph> pl = xdoc.getParagraphs();
for (XWPFParagraph p : pl) {
    List<CTMarkupRange> markups = p.getCTP().getCommentRangeStartList();
    for (CTMarkupRange markup: markups) {
        XWPFComment commentText = xdoc.getCommentByID(markup.getId().toString());
        System.out.println(commentText.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.dev.ananth;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.IBodyElement;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFComment;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTMarkupRange;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class ExtractCommentText {
    public static void main(String[] a) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        String fileName = "D:\\test.docx";
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        XWPFDocument xdoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = xdoc.getParagraphs();
        Map<String, CommentDto> map=new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<String, Boolean> checkMap=new LinkedHashMap<>();
        List<CommentDto> list=new LinkedList<>();
        
        for (XWPFParagraph p : paragraphs) {
            List<CTMarkupRange> markups = p.getCTP().getCommentRangeStartList();
            for (CTMarkupRange markup : markups) {
                System.out.println("Comment Id: "+markup.getId());
                boolean hasComment=false;
                String commentReferenceText = "";
                String startId="";
                String endId="";
                XmlCursor xmlCursor =markup.newCursor();
                while ( xmlCursor.hasNextToken()){
                
                     Node node = xmlCursor.getDomNode();
                    
                     if(hasComment) {
                         if(node.getNodeName().contains("#text") ) {
                             commentReferenceText +=  node.getNodeValue();
                         }
                         
                     }
                     if(node.getNodeName().contains("w:commentRangeStart")) {
                         Attr attr = (Attr) node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("w:id");
                            if (attr != null) {
                                 startId = attr.getValue();
                            }
                         
                         if(markup.getId().toString() .equals(startId)) {
                             hasComment=true;
                         }
                     }
                     else if(node.getNodeName().contains("w:commentRangeEnd")) {
                         Attr attr = (Attr) node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("w:id");
                            if (attr != null) {
                                 endId = attr.getValue();
                                //System.out.println("endId: " + endId);
                            }
                         
                             if(markup.getId().toString() .equals(endId)) {
                                 hasComment=false;
                                 XWPFComment comment = xdoc.getCommentByID(markup.getId().toString());
                                    System.out.println("comment text: "+commentReferenceText);
                                    System.out.println("comment: "+comment.getText());
                                    
                                 break;
                             }
                     }
                     xmlCursor.toNextToken();
            }
        }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```